# .then code is ignored(not executing )in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have 3 functions

- 1.getAdharVerified() //gets adhar info from firebase and validates age later
- registeElec()   // register election details in firebase (adds data to firebase)
- 3.createElection() //creates election in blockchain smart contract

I have to execute these functions in the same order I have a code using .then after every function but .then part is not executing

after executing first function it avoids then part and goes to last line

here is my function

```
void startElectionComplete() {
    // the code to start election from adhar verification,register election and create election at blockchain

    if (kDebugMode) {print('verifying adhar');}
    getAdharVerified(adharTextController.text).then((value) => (){ //ADHAR VERIFICATION FUNCTION
      showSnackBar(snackbarshow().succesAdharSnack);

      if (kDebugMode) {print('adhar verified');}
      if (_adharage > 18 && privateKeyTextController.text.isNotEmpty) {  // CHECKING AGE FROM ADHAR

        if (kDebugMode) {print('adhar verification complete');}  // CHECKING WEATHER ELECTION DATES ARE GIVEN
        if(unixlast != null &&unixlast.isNotEmpty){
          if(unix !=null && unix.isNotEmpty){
            if (kDebugMode) {print('unix not nulll');}

            try{
              if (kDebugMode) {print('registering');}
              registerElec(unix,unixlast).then((value) => ()  {// REGISTERING THE ELECTION IN FIREBASE
                if (kDebugMode) {print('creating blockchain');}
                //AFTER REGISTRATION CREATING ELECTION ON BLOCKCHAN
                createElection(electionNameTextController.text, ethclient!, privateKeyTextController.text, contractAdressConst);
                showSnackBar(snackbarshow().succesAdharSnack);
              });
              gotoPickElec();
            }catch(e){
              if (kDebugMode) {
                print(e);
              }

              showSnackBar(errorAdharSnack);
            }if (kDebugMode) {print('there is a problemmm');}
          }showSnackBar(errorSnack);
        }showSnackBar(errorSnack);
      }showSnackBar(errorSnack);
    });print('i am now out of then part');

  }
```

log output for better understanding

```
I/flutter ( 6105): the unix time stamp is 1672770600
I/flutter ( 6105): the unix time stamp is 1672857000
I/flutter ( 6105): verifying adhar
I/flutter ( 6105): i am now out of then part
```

I don't understand what wrong happened here is there any way to do this in less time and more faster way? please explain what happened so that I can understand what is going on here,thankyou

Comment: "I have to execute these functions in the same order" - why don't you use `await` keyword then? more here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: @pskink I am not using await because I don't want to execute a function only without others  that means if a function throws an error I don't want other functions to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls to Firebase are futures. The .then statement says that when the future returns something, it executes that code. So far so good,. However, the code doesn't stop, waiting for the future to complete, it continues to the next line of code after the .then. In this scenario, I recommend you use asymc await, rather than .then clauses. The .then has its uses but probably not in this case.

Also, your try catch seems too low down. It needs to be able to catch   an error from all of the firebase calls.

Comment: so if I use await and async if one function throws an error will the other functions execute successfully, I clearly don't want that to happen if a function is successful I want all functions to be successful if not I don't want any function to be successful because I use firebase and blockchain for storing data

Comment: As long as all the awaits are within the one try catch then the catch will happen on that await and any code after the await will not be executed. You can always put each awaited code in its own try catch, for micro control if you need it. You can also use the finally clause to clean stuff up if needed. https://www.darttutorial.org/dart-tutorial/dart-try-catch-finally/

Comment: If the successful execution of the all three database calls, or none of them, is crucial then you may need to look at firebase transactions or batch / atomic updates to ensure all succeed or all fail. I don't know bloc so can't comment on the implications there.